# document.execCommand

Tags: javascript, text, range, edit

How can I create my own document.execCommand? So for example I want to create something like center the text(execCommand support only justifyCenter,justifyLeft,justifyRight) or if I want to create aligment for images.

Comment: You can't add new `document.execCommand` commands in JavaScript. Your best bet is to hope Tim Down appears out of the sky like a superhero and drops some `range` knowledge bombs on you.

Comment: @George02 - FYI, [Tim Down](http://stackoverflow.com/users/96100/tim-down) is the one who created [Rangy](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/). ;)

Comment: I did some work on a generic `execCommand()` module for Rangy last year but abandoned it (temporarily, hopefully) when it got a bit tricky.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not create your own `document.execCommand`, but you can use [Rangy](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/wiki/RangyRange) to modify text selection.

For example, if you want to center text, try this:
http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/h9Ym2/

See more demos [here](http://rangy.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/).

Comment: In particular, the [CSS class applier module](http://rangy.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/cssclassapplier.html) may help if centering the text using a class is an acceptable solution.